# "Warning! Could not get a mongodb connection string" message logged in new RHMAP cloud app?

Tags: mongodb, rhmap

Issue

When I create a new cloud app, why do I get the following warning message in the error logs:

> no way to determine mongo connection string 
>   Warning! Could not get a
>   mongodb connection string. Sync will not work. If running in a
>   Dynofarm/FeedHenry MBaaS, ensure the database is upgraded

Any help apprecianted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Data Browser section of your Cloud app and click Upgrade Database.

It will ask you to re deploy the cloud app and this time that message shouldn't appear on the logs.